# Why does Google Apps Mail leak IP address? How do I disable it?

Tags: email, g-suite, gmail, privacy

When sending via Google Apps Mail client the message will include a 'X-Originating-IP' header.

**But when sending via Gmail and using the SMTP send-mail-as option it will not leak the ip address. (Yes it goes through the proper Google Apps account SMTP).**

Why does this happen? If I don't want my IP address leaked I have to open up Gmail and send an email with it (as someone else) instead of just using the premium Google Apps Mail interface...

I really don't think they should be leaking IP addresses anyway. Understandable that a on-site exchange server would leak the originating IP address but why would a customer want Google Apps to leak it?

Is there anyway to disable the header in the App admin panel? I cannot find any option currently.

And is there any alternative to Google Apps that does not leak IP like this?

Answer (score 6):

The source IP address of mail is almost always recorded in email headers, no matter what method you use.

These serve a purpose - to track down spam, viruses spreading, etc.  Sysadmins need to know where the mail came from to help stop these things.

Your IP address isn't a secret.  Every website and other system your computer connects to knows it.  If, for some reason, you really need to hide your IP address look into anonymous proxies like TOR.  Otherwise, its just a normal part of being on the internet.

Comment: Exactly. There is nothing "leaking" here.

Comment: That is not true. If you use gmail.com, your IP address is not leaked in the headers.  It's only in Google Apps that it leaks this information. Try it out yourself. I have